# How can I use holder.js inside an #each loop in Handlebars (Ember.js) template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, holder.js

I'm looping through an array of objects in an Ember.js Handlebars template and trying to display a placeholder image for each using [holder.js](http://imsky.github.io/holder/).

Outside of the #each loop context, holder.js renders the placeholder image as expected:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100x100" src='' alt='person image' />

{{#each person in controller}}
  person.name
{{/each}}
```

When *inside* the #each loop, no placeholder images appear:

```
{{#each person in controller}}
  <img data-src="holder.js/100x100" src='' alt='person image' />
  person.name
{{/each}}
```

Perhaps there's something I'm not understanding about how #each loops work, but is there a trick to getting placeholder images to appear here?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/imafuq/8/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `Holder.run()` is called before `Ember` loops through all your data, so you have to call it yourself again at a later point.

You could try adding

```
Em.run.schedule('afterRender', null, function () { Holder.run(); })
```

or

```
Em.run.next(function () { Holder.run(); })
```

to the `renderTemplate` hook of your route. (Even better would be to add it after you know your controller has been loaded with all your data.)

Answer (score 3):

I just want to be a bit more explicit in case anyone like me runs into similar problems or gets themselves confused with how it works.

First, add a View for your template if you don't have one. If you're working with the MushroomsRoute, create a MushroomsView. Inside your view, do something like this:

```
App.MushroomsView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.run.next(function() {
            Holder.run();
        })
     }
});
```

And that should work -- or at least it does with Ember 1.0.0.